# Nested if calculated column, checks for 3 columns if blank to update a status

Tags: list, custom-list, calculated-column, list-form, calculated-column-formula

I have this formula that does not work, really stumped. I've worked through this several times and just can't quite get it.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Find("4",Priority)),"Deferred",(IF(ISBLANK([Close Date]),(IF(ISBLANK([Actual Fix Date]),(IF(ISBLANK([Estimated Fix Date]),"Open","Accepted"),"Fixed"),"Closed"))
```

The calculated formula checks for if the priority is deferred, because if so the overall status is then deferred. It then checks if there are any values for dates in 3 columns. Please let me know if there is something blatantly wrong or if there is another way to go about doing this, thank you!

Comment: Are you getting the "bad formula" error, or is it not giving you the results you're looking for given the conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't putting the correct amount of parentheses. You have 12 '(' but only 9 ')' which means the functions in your function aren't being closed properly. Try adding three ')' at the end of your function.

Comment: Did not work, I've tried working the parentheses in other spots as well. I'm sure it's a syntax error but maybe it's a logic error? Can nested if statements work like this in sharepoint or maybe it isn't supported.

Comment: It is definitely allowed. There are examples for nested if statements here: [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a). Sometimes it helps to start building it from the ground up again, to see how the logic of your function pans out.

Comment: Thanks for the help stranger, got it to finally work.

Here's the final if anyone ever comes across this thread and wants free sp code lol =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("4",Priority)),"Deferred",IF(ISBLANK([Estimated Fix Date]),"Open",IF(ISBLANK([Actual Fix Date]),"Accepted",IF(ISBLANK([Close Date]),"Fixed","Closed"))))

Comment: Glad I could help! Nothing worse than banging your head against a while and not finding a solution ..

Comment: @ColtonM. Please if the above answer guide you to solve your issue, set it as answer, if not at your final answer in answer section to be helpful for all, thanks